# Noisy edges on my animation

Tags: noise-reduction

[image]

I'm rendering an animation and don't know how to smooth these noisy edges - sampling is also high. I tried clamping to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/. Let us know if none of these methods work.

Comment: What resolution are you rendering at? That looks like you just have a low resolution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image of your render settings.

Comment: Resolution is 1920 x 1080 with 100%. Plane is 20% of all image but this white pixels is still annoyng even in 1:1 view.
Im pined in post all sampling and light path settings.
Im was trying this methods and many of other. Surface of plane is clean. But on edges is very noisy and i dont know why.

Comment: Bring up the **AA (anti aliasing) Samples** for render to at least 4 (and at that point you can bring the number of samples to one quarter of what you have now ie. bring the diffuse to 256, glossy to 515, since they will then be multiplied by 4

Comment: im pinned in post what that does.
im think its kind a bug.

Comment: I don't think is a bug at all. Your antialiasing settings are too low. We haven't seen any more information on your file and all of the other settings that might cause this. Can you please upload your file? You can use: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and [edit] the resulting link into your question.

Comment: **It's not a bug.**

Answer (score 1):

Don't use branched path tracing.

If you really REALLY *REALLY* want to use branched path tracing, then you need to increase your Anti-Aliasing samples. For each ONE pass on one pixel, you're doing **1024** Diffuse samples, and **2048** Glossy samples, but only **1** AA sample. Your Diffuse and Glossy settings are **multiplied** by the number of AA samples you use. Secondly, your AA settings define how many "passes" each pixel is given. You're only making two passes.

...and don't use branched path tracing.

Editorial: The only reason I say not to use branched path tracing (BPT) is that it's a specialized tool for solving a particular problem. Using it for a situation like this is unnecessarily complicated and creates more problems than it solves. It's common for Blenderheads to use BPT because they think of it like a one-button-click that "makes things better," but there's *only one thing* that BPT can do better: render faster... sometimes.

Don't worry about speed until speed becomes the bottleneck that you need to solve right now. And BPT is only faster if you know how to set it up for *your particular use-case.* Otherwise, it's likely to create more problems than it solves.

It's like the old adage about optimizing code "The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet." — Michael A. Jackson

Similarly, the first rule of BPT should be "Don't use it," and the second rule (for experts only!) "Don't use it yet."

Comment: While I agree on the Anti-aliasing  (as noted by my comments), I would love to get a deeper explanation of why not to use branched path tracing

Comment: I'll editorialize a bit in my answer ;-)